# Create a newform after clicking the print button

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am a new developer and learning.

i am creating an application in Blazor Web assembly.

issue : I am using mudblazor library in my project . I  created a button to print, which calls the Print Function. when you click on the button it will print that particular page.

Requirement - when i click on the button it should generate a new form  which  should include data from other pages  and that form should be printed directly .

current approach.
i can make a button and put the refence to another page which will have info from all other pages and then click print to print the new razor page.

Help - i was just wondering is there a way i can do this without creating a new razor page and i can use methods or function that can generate a new form in the backend and will automatically come to the print page without it getting displayed.

FYI- i already have a method in place which can print the page i want but will only print the page that is currently displayed.

Currently looking for a solution for this.

Comment: It's really hard for anyone to provide a good, solid answer without seeing any of the code that you have written so far. Check out: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in **DynamicComponent** component to render components by type. DynamicComponent can render a component based on a user selection from a dropdown list.

```html
<DynamicComponent Type="@componentType" Parameters="@parameters" />

@code {
    private Type componentType = ...;
    private IDictionary<string, object> parameters = ...;
}
```

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-6.0#example-1